# Check if user is a member of the local admins group on a remote server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The user is a member of the AD security group "Domain\Sql Admins", and the security group "Domain\Sql Admins" is a member of the local **Administrators** group on a Windows Server.

I have tried the following PowerShell script:

```
 $u = "Username"; net localgroup administrators | Where {$_ -match $u}
```

This script will only return the user if it is added directly to the admin group. Do I have to cycle through all of the groups in the admin group until I find my user? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out this article, by Boe Prox on the Microsoft Hey Scripting Guy blog. He describes how to check if the user is a local administrator or not.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/11/check-for-admin-credentials-in-a-powershell-script.aspx

This article points to a `Test-IsAdmin` function that was posted onto the TechNet Gallery.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1b5df952-9e10-470f-ad7c-dc2bdc2ac946

The function contains the following code, which returns `$true` or `$false`.

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")
```

Answer (score 9):

PowerShell 5.1 (Windows Server 2016) contains [Get-LocalGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlet.

```
$user = "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME"
$group = 'Administrators'
$isInGroup = (Get-LocalGroupMember $group).Name -contains $user
```

Comment: I wish `query.exe` was available with Windows 10 Home, but it is not, only the Pro version has it.

Comment: @cbaldan how about `quser` on home, is it available?

Comment: This should be a "-Match" instead of a "-Contains" most likely because of accounts with the computer name in front  (e.g. "SYSTEM_NAME\USERID")

Comment: This does not handle the case when domain user is memeber of local Administrators group. In that case it should be: `(Get-LocalGroupMember 'Administrators').Name -contains "$env:UserDomain\$env:UserName"`

Answer (score 2):

Using the SID:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups | Select-String 'S-1-5-32-544')
```

Or using a "Well-known" security identifier name:

```
([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups.IsWellKnown('BuiltinAdministratorsSid') -eq $true)
```

if you want to get all the SIDs and their names, please check this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be using the [PowerShell Community Extension](http://pscx.codeplex.com) you can use the `Test-UserGroupMembership` command e.g.:

```
Test-UserGroupMembership Administrators
```